# flutter navigator do when action after call pushReplacement in child page

Tags: flutter, push, navigator

I have a flutter app look like this

PAGE 1 > PAGE 2 > PAGE 3

When I change value on PAGE 2, I need to refresh data on PAGE 1 so I using **Navigator.push** from PAGE 1 to PAGE 2 with **then** action in PAGE 1. When I navigator from PAGE 2 to PAGE 3 by **Navigator.pushReplacement** (to escape from PAGE 3 to PAGE 1 when press back button) but when I navigator from PAGE 2 to PAGE 3 then **when** action are calling in PAGE 1 and when I press back button on PAGE 3 then action **when** are not calling

How can I still refresh data on PAGE 1 and when press back button on PAGE 3? and not call **when** action when navigator from PAGE 2 to PAGE 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any state management pattern like provider, you can easily update your data in PAGE 1 from anywhere under provider widget, have a look [LINK_HERE](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Comment: thanks it work with provider